# Create video from pictures saved in sd-card on Android

Tags: android, video-processing

I have read many threads about how to create videos from images on Android. I am a bit confused about how can I get it work. 
Some posts says that we can use a ffmpeg library for android. I have seen other posts talking about the library Media Format. Some other posts have two years and maybe has been some changes.

Right now, what is the simplest way to create a video from images (regardless how eficient is the process)?

Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing built into Android for this. You will need to use some third-party library, `ffmpeg` or otherwise.

Comment: Ok, I will try with ffmpeg so. I believed that after two years maybe some changes had happened in this field, but I realize that no. Thanks @CommonsWare .

Comment: have u solved ur problem?if yes then please share it to me this is a big issue for me..thanks

Comment: @FarhanShah I ended up using JavaCV, that incorporates all the tools for encoding a video from images by means of an interface, without having to deal with NDK code. I think is one of the painless solutions: https://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Comment: i want to make videos from images with background sounds,can u please specify me a right direction?

Comment: @FarhanShah First of all, read carefully the instructions of how to use JavaCV, in his webpage there are some pretty straightforward examples of how to use that library. Once you have all the images that you want to use in a folder, then you will use the methods that the library provide to convert all your photos to a video, it only requires a few lines of code. The community behind this project is nice and I'm sure that you will find support if you have troubles. Anyway, what you are trying to do is not new, check this post: http://goo.gl/JxdkVc .

Comment: @MatiesPons Bundle of Thanks for your reply,ok i am start reading and following your instruction and also start implementing,thanks alot for your guidence and instructions :)

Comment: @FarhanShah You are welcome, hope it helps.